# How to return name of sub or function from a function in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have a sub in VBScript code. I want to print the name of the sub whenever I call that from my script.
for example, It should work like below:

```
for i=0 to 3  
 PrintSubName  
Next  


Sub PrintSubName()  
 Print PrintSubName.name '''Here some code that prints name of the sub like "PrintSubName"  
End Sub
```

Output should be:

```
PrintSubName  
PrintSubName  
PrintSubName  
PrintSubName
```

Comment: VBScript doesn't support type introspection, so you can't have functions tell you their name. You need to hard-code it into the function.

Comment: Tried to find the same: no luck. I had to  hardcode it